# If statements with Background Colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i just wanted to see where i am going wrong with these if statements i cant see anything wrong with them, but they do not seem to work as intended which is too switch color when a html button is clicked i am already sure that is working as console displays "Button Clicked" when clicking the button.

```
 function colorSwitch()
 {
 var thediv = document.getElementsByClassName("light");

 console.log("Button Clicked");

if(thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#ff0000")
{
 thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
}
if(thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#ffff00")
{
 thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
}
if(thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#00ff00")
{
 thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
}

};
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of copy and pasting there. There are better ways of doing it using an object. FYI: Not all browsers return hex.

Answer (score 1):

You need add the keyword `else`, otherwise each condition is being met, making you go full circle.

```
function colorSwitch () {
  var thediv = document.getElementsByClassName("light");

  console.log("Button Clicked");

  if (thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#ff0000") {
    thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
  }
  else if (thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#ffff00") {
    thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
  }
  else if (thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#00ff00") {
    thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One `if` statement is being asked directly after the other on each click; meaning they're all becoming true as you get further down the method.

Including an `else` statement is one way to go.

The other way is using an `Array` of colours, presuming you want a particular order:

```js
var colors = ["#ff0000", "#ffff00", "#00ff00"];
var switched = 0;

function colorSwitch () {

  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("light");
  
  elements[0].style.backgroundColor = colors[switched % colors.length];

  switched++;
  
};
```

```css
.light {
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 3em;
  
  border-radius: .25em;

  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="light" onclick="javascript:colorSwitch();">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the background color each if block. You need to change it to either an [if-else if-else format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), switch case, or use an object to select the new color.

```
function colorSwitch()
{
   var thediv = document.getElementsByClassName("light");

  console.log("Button Clicked");

  if(thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#ff0000")
  {
     thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
  }
  else if(thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#ffff00")
  {
     thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
  }
  else if(thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#00ff00")
  {
     thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
  }
}
```

or you can do :

```
var colorMap = {
    "#ff0000": "#ffff00",
    "#ffff00":"#00ff00",
    "#00ff00": "#ff0000"
}
thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = colorMap[thediv[0].style.backgroundColor];
```

or [switch-case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

```
switch(thediv[0].style.backgroundColor)
{
    case "#ff0000":
        thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
        break;
    case "#ffff00":
        thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
        break;
    case "#00ff00":
        thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you run this code:
`thediv[0].style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00"`
the statement `thediv[0].style.backgroundColor == "#00ff00"` will return false(at least for my chrome console)

Also, as the other guys pointed out, you need to use else